# Google App Engine with Firebase trimmed JSON response

Tags: json, firebase, google-app-engine, response

After implementing Firebase Auth in my GAE backend, I am stuck with a a trimmed JSON response problem. The authentication process works fine, I successfuly identify users in my GAE backend. The problem appears when I am receiving the JSON response. From backend perspective everything looks fine - HTTP code 200, no error in Log Viewer, apart of the response which is just trimmed (it contains propper data but is trimmed at the end), and thus could not be parsed further and used by application.

What I did was the following:

1. For a backward compatibility reasons I used two authenticators, so my current android app would work until users upgrade for a new version with implemented Firebse Auth:

```
authenticators = {EndpointsAuthenticator.class, EspAuthenticator.class}
```

2. I followed a Guice Firebase integration example:
   https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java8/endpoints-v2-guice
3. I generated and deployed an Open Api Docs:

```
gcloud endpoints services deploy openapi.json
```

Interesting though, if I deploy the openapi.json with removed content of section "paths" and call the api with Google OAuth JWT token (this type of token doesn't need openapi.json) e.g. using curl, I get the full response.

When openapi.json contains generated "paths" defs, I always get trimmed result and it is not relevant which type (Google OAuth/Firebase) of the JWT token I'm using.

My Api class config:

```
@Api(
  name = "myApi",
  version = "v1",
  authenticators = {EndpointsAuthenticator.class, EspAuthenticator.class},
  issuers = {
    @ApiIssuer(
            name = "firebase",
            issuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/myapiname",
            jwksUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com")
  },
  issuerAudiences = {
    @ApiIssuerAudience(name = "firebase", audiences = "myapiname")
  },
  clientIds = {
          Constants.API_BROWSER_ID,
          Constants.ANDROID_DEV, Constants.ANDROID_PROD,
          Constants.ANDROID_DEV_PAID, Constants.ANDROID_PROD_PAID,
          Constants.WEB_DEV, Constants.WEB_PROD
  },
  audiences = {
          Constants.ANDROID_DEV, Constants.ANDROID_PROD,
          Constants.ANDROID_DEV_PAID, Constants.ANDROID_PROD_PAID,
          Constants.WEB_DEV, Constants.WEB_PROD
  },
  namespace = @ApiNamespace(
    ownerDomain = "myapiname.mydomain",
    ownerName = "Jacek F"
  )
)
```

My graddle.build:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        // V2: Add the new App Engine and Endpoints Frameworks plugin dependencies
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:2.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:1.3.3'
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter();
}

def projectId = 'myapiname'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

// V2: Apply new App Engine and Endpoints Framework server plugins
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-server'


sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

dependencies {
    // V2: Endpoints Framework v2 migration
    implementation 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework:2.0.9'
    implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    implementation 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:24.1-jre'
    implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'

    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.7'

    implementation 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-management-control-appengine:1.0.12'
    implementation 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework-auth:1.0.12'
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.12.2'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.30.2'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.30.2'

    implementation 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework-guice:2.0.9'
}

endpointsServer {
    // Endpoints Framework Plugin server-side configuration
    hostname = "${projectId}.appspot.com"
    serviceClasses = ['mydomain.myapi.MyEndpoint']

}

// this replaces the ${endpoints.project.id} in appengine-web.xml and web.xml
task replaceProjectId(type: Copy) {
    from 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/'
    include '*.xml'
    into "build/exploded-${archivesBaseName}/WEB-INF"
    expand(endpoints:[project:[id:projectId]])
    filteringCharset = 'UTF-8'
}
assemble.dependsOn replaceProjectId
```

I stumbled upon some discussions related to unstable responses caused by protobuf https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/google-cloud-endpoints/eqxNqq8k4jA, but upgrading all my deps to the latest version did not solve the issue.

Do you have any tips or ideas?

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that verbalization of the problem helped - upgrading remaining deps, fixed my API :)

```
implementation 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework:2.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework-guice:2.2.1'
```